# Merge latest and pending pull request with new branch on Git repo

Tags: git

A Git scenario:

1. I branch off origin/develop and work on a feature branch called F1.
2. I push F1 and submit a pull request.
3. The pull request is pending.

Now I want to create a branch for another feature - F2.  F2 relies on F1 and also relies on some new additions to develop made by other developers.

In other words I want to create branch F2 that has F1 and the latest from develop.

What is the / an appropriate workflow for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your new branch from `F1` and merge `develop` into it, or create from `develop` and merge `F1` into it. The end result is the same in terms of content, just the revision tree will have a different shape, which shouldn't really matter.

When `F2` is ready, create a pull request. But only after `F1` was already accepted. If you create a PR for `F2` before `F1` is accepted, you will inconvenience the reviewer, as in that case `F2` and `F1` will both be in that PR.

Reviewing pull requests is all about reviewing the diff between the source branch and the target branch. If `F1` was accepted already, then only the unique changes in `F2` will show up in the diff. It doesn't matter how many other branches have been merged into `F2`, as long as they have already been merged into the target, they won't show up in the diff, so the reviewer can concentrate on the unique changes of `F2`.

While working on `F2`, if there is a change in `F1`, you can merge that if you need it. It doesn't really matter. After `F1` is accepted into the target, the reviewer will only see the unique changes of `F2`, it won't matter how many times it merged from `F1`, and it doesn't have to contain the entire `F1`.

Answer (score 0):

Start `F2` on top of `F1` and merge in the additions from `origin/develop`.  Once the pull request for `F1` has been accepted, rebase `F2` on top of the new `origin/develop` and submit a pull request for `F2`.